# loading/switching child views inside main view in sencha touch 2

Tags: user-interface, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am creating a Sencha Touch app which has one main view with a left side panel and a top titlebar. In the middle I want to load different different views based on click on left side items. How can I achieve that?
If I do `Ext.viewport.add(view);` it will add new view on top of my main view making main view's left panel not visible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have done this kind of thing before using the Navigation View - http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View

So you just push or pop views as you require so only one is visible at a time, you can still keep your side bar, and so when you click a side bar item you would perform the push as shown in the docs.

Comment: no but i dont want to use navigation view. I have simple Containers view and I want to show them in child of main view.

Comment: Well the navigation view will allow you to do exactly that

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an `Ext.navigation.View` an `Ext.Container` will be enough. Use its `add()` method to add a child, before adding items you could call `removeAll()` to remove the existing objects.

Anyway I don't see any reasons for not using `Ext.navigation.View` which handles for you the card layout and the animations.

You could use a layout like this:

```
MainView (Ext.Container) layout:hbox
  |_ TitleBar (Ext.TitleBar) docked:top
  |_ LeftPanel (Ext.Container) flex:1
  |    |_ (Ext.Button)
  |    |_ (Ext.Button)
  |_ ContentPanel (Ext.navigation.View) flex:2
```

You should push views on `tap` event of the LeftPanel buttons.